# How to change the target type for .bat files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

[image]When I installed the Notepad++ in windows 7. Some settings changed the target type for .bat files. Now whenever I try to open the batch files by double clicking on it, the file opens in the text mode displaying the commands in the notepad++ instead of running the batch file. Is there any way to restore the default setting without installing any additional software?

Answer (score 1):

You must have set the default type of application to startup as txt file. You need to change it to cmd to fix this.
XYZ.bat=batfile
type this in the command prompt by going to the directory of the file.
run the command prompt as administrator.
Go to commnd prompt. Open the location type ASSOC .bat=batfile this will fix the issue.
Run it in administrator mode.

Comment: Hi archit, it doesn't give me any option to edit the type of file in properties.So do not know ow to change it.

Comment: Go to commnd prompt. Open the location type ASSOC .bat=batfile
this will fix the issue

Comment: I was able to run the command. "C:\test>ASSOC xyz.bat=batfile
xyz.bat=batfile" But unfortunately the file type is still showing as Notepad++ document. Thanks a lot for all your efforts and help. Sincerely, plus one.

Comment: @archit, please consider to include the above comments in your answer...

Comment: @aschipfl I have added them.Thanks.

Comment: I am still unable to change the type, any thoughts please?